# catching an error and then branching logic

Tags: r, error-handling

How do I write R code that allows me to execute a different path in my code if an error condition happens? I'm using a function that tends to throw an error. When it meets an error condition I would like to execute a different function. Here's a specific example:

```
require(SuppDists)
parms <- structure(list(gamma = -0.841109044800762, delta = 0.768672140584442, 
    xi = -0.359199299528801, lambda = 0.522761187947026, type = "SB"), .Names = c("gamma", 
"delta", "xi", "lambda", "type"))
pJohnson(.18, parms)
```

the pJohnson function should fail with the following error:

```
 Error in pJohnson(0.18, parms) :
 Sb values out of range.
```

I can make the error go silent by using:

```
try( pJohnson(.18, parms), silent=T)
```

but what I really want to do is execute the function `alternativeFunction()` if `pJohnson(.18, parms)` returns an error.

It seems like the `withCallingHandlers()` function should help me out, but I can't figure out how to capture the error and make it run the `alternativeFunction()` only upon an error condition.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
t <- try(pJohnson(.18, parms))
if("try-error" %in% class(t)) alternativeFunction()
```

Comment: clearly a case of me not thinking "objecty" enough. thank you for the fast response!

Comment: `if (inherits(t, "try-error")) alternativeFunction()`   is a nice alternative that is even more 'objecty' than the `%in%`.

Comment: Good point. The object abstraction layer for s3 classes is so transparent, I almost forget that it is there.

Answer (score 21):

Another option might be to use a `tryCatch` expression.  Here's an example:

```
 vari <- 1
 tryCatch(print("passes"),  error = function(e) print(vari)) # => passes
 tryCatch(stop("fails"),  error = function(e) print(vari)) # => 1
```

You can do whatever you want within the error block, so in your case, something like this should work:

```
tryCatch(pJohnson(.18, parms), error=function(e) alternativeFunction())
```

This isn't really the intended usage of the error, but it's a little more concise.