# How can I do error handling with read_excel when the file exists but it can be read?

Tags: r

is there a way to do error handling using function "read_excel" from R when the file exists, but it can't be read for some other reason (e.g., wrong format or something)?

Just to illustrate, my piece of code is as follows:

```
f <- GET(url, authenticate(":", ":", type="ntlm"), write_disk(tf <- tempfile(tmpdir = here("data/temp"), fileext = ".xlsx")))
dt <- read_excel(tf)
```

where url contains the http file address.

I would like to check if read_excel returns an error to do the proper handling and prevent the markdown stops.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a duplicate question. The code below is modified from the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158780/catching-an-error-and-then-branching-logic). The *someOtherFunction* in the code below is where one can have some function to run if there is an error.

```
f <- GET(url, authenticate(":", ":", type="ntlm"), write_disk(tf <- tempfile(tmpdir = here("data/temp"), fileext = ".xlsx")))

t <- try(read_excel(tf))

if("try-error" %in% class(t)) SomeOtherFunction()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sidhartha, for the fastest response ever! I really apreciated - it worked very fine:) (didnt know the function "try") thanks again